# initiate the ArrayList with maximum size

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Is it possible in initiate the ArrayList with fixed size so it may not increase more than that and initiate all the initial occupancy to 0? in actual forcing it to behave like an ordinary Array so we can use the add() upto to the array size.

Comment: No it's not. This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what are you trying to achieve? Maybe a bounded queue would be more appropriate?

Comment: why don't you use a normal array itself then? What is the exact motive?

Comment: try using other arraylist implementations like LinkedList for example

Comment: @mattymanme A `LinkedList` is not "another arraylist implementation". And how would using a `LinkedList` solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use normal `array` rather than `ArrayList`

ArrayList are basically simply an array with support for the situation where we may have to add more items. If we're not changing the size of that ArrayList than it's just like the conventional array

Comment: i would love to use it but i want to initiale an arraylist with 5 size, all assigned initally to zero. then start over and assign 1 from start based on some condition so in the end if i have all 5 elemnts 1, which means the test is succesful, otherwise if a single zero is there it will indicate false.

Comment: What's the problem with using normal `array`. You can initialize an array of size 5 and during the time of initialization, all the values would be zero and then you can continue your operations with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[desiredLength]);
```

to produce a fixed size `List<Integer>` in which all the elements are initialized to `null`. Then you can use `list.set(index,value)` to modify elements of that `List`. You can't use `add` though, since `add` changes the `size` of the `List`, which is not allowed in fixed sized lists.

If you want to initialize the List to non-null values, you can do something like this :

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[desiredLength];
Arrays.fill(arr,0);
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Comment: Probably the best approach, though it doesn't produce an actual ArrayList.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia An actual ArrayList (i.e. java.util.ArrayList) doesn't have a fixed size as requested by the OP.

Comment: Yes I know :) I just thought it was worth mentioning it in case he tries to assign it to an AL and gets puzzled by the error

Answer (score 1):

You can, by using only arraylist, ensure a minimum size of the arraylist:

```
ArrayList<T> myArrayList = new ArrayList();
myArrayList.ensureCapacity(n);
```

But that doesn't set a fixed size, just something bigger than n, and it doesn't prevent you to add more than n.

As mentioned by other, you are probably better off doing something else. If you really want to achieve that, you can write your own collection:

```
public class MyArrayList<T> {
  ArrayList<T> arrayList;
  int size;

  public MyArrayList(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.ensureCapacity(size);
  }

  public void add(T x) {
    if (arrayList.size() >= size) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    arrayList.add(x);
  }

  //remove, etc.. . You can even extend/implement arrayList/list if you want to do polymorphism.
}
```